# Compiling Java package throws errors for external Jars

Tags: java, classpath

Pretty basic problem here.  So I have a Java package that I have created that has three classes (one has the main method).  I am trying to use a few Apache Jars, and have added these to my build path in Eclipse.  However Eclipse wont let me build and run it properly, so I am trying the command line.  I have added the env var CLASSPATH and pointed it to my lib directory which hold the Apache Jars.  However, when I try to use javac I get a bunch of errors:

```
package org.apache.xmlrpc does not exist
import org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient;
```

I was reading the man page for javac and it said that:

```
 If neither CLASSPATH, -cp nor -classpath is specified, the user class path consists of the current directory.
```

So I tried copying the Jars to the same location as my three source files, but no change.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please post the exact javac command line you execute as well as the errors you get ?

Comment: Great, yeah I was just adding the directory to the classpath.  Adding the individual Jars sorted it out.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classpath variable (or command line option of javac) must contain all jars explicitly. It cannot go through jar files stored in specified directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile this by specifying the option -cp on the command line:

```
javac -cp foo.jar:bar.jar foo/bar/Baz.java
```

You then run it with the same option:

```
java -cp foo.jar:bar.jar foo.bar.Baz
```

Comment: You don't need to specify the classpath on the command line - but you *do* need to specify the jar files explicitly, instead of just giving a directory.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've just set the classpath to the *directory* containing the jar files. You need to set it to the individual jar files, or use `java.ext.dirs` to set an "extension" directory containing jar files. I'd recommend using the specific jar files. Something like:

```
// Assuming Windows...
CLASSPATH = c:\libs\foo.jar;c:\libs\bar.jar
```

I'd also personally recommend specifying the classpath on the command line instead of using an environment variable - the latter will work, but it ends up being a bit more fiddly if you want to compile different projects against different libraries.

However, I'd *actually* recommend getting Eclipse working first, rather than retreating to the command line. It should be fine - if you could give us more information about what's failing in Eclipse, we may be able to help you with that instead.

Answer (score 0):

The jar files in the current directory are not automatically included; that only refers to `.class` files in normal package/directory hierarchy. Jar files must be added either explicitly, or via a wildcard like `javac -cp ./*` (Assuming JDK6+)

(Some OSes may require an escape of the `*` to avoid globbing; OSX does not.)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with previous answers, but I would also recommend to use  proper java build tool - like ant (perceived easier to use,  but not necessary) or maven ( perceived more difficult to use, but really worth learning )